# CSS: body background color displays locally, but not on the Web

Tags: html, css

The styles.css file I used to use has this body stanza:

```
body {
    font: 18px Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url("../images/bg.jpg") center top repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
        line-height: 20px;
}
```

and it displays that gradient color both locally and on the Web.

I want to replace the gradient with a solid medium blue color so I modified the body stanza to this:

```
body {
    font: 18px Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #00008B;
    background-size: cover;
        line-height: 20px;
}
```

This works when I view my web site locally, but on the Web the body background-color is white so no text can be seen.

Why might changing from body background using an image to body background-color using a hex code display differently on the Web?

Comment: there's the chance you have a conflicting css rule engaging on the document that will trigger only when you visit the version where the background doesn't work. Such rule probably overrides this one. Did you check with the browser inspect element which styles get applied to the body element?

Comment: probably a caching issue or a specificity weight issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the background property to set the hex color

```
body {
font: 18px Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #00008B;
background-size: cover;
    line-height: 20px;
background: blue;
```

}

Comment: Thank you. that worked perfectly. I'll not know why background-color didn't work when background does, but I'm not a professional web developer so I'll now go back to business.